# Android: App can't be found from Tablets

Tags: android, manifest, qt5

After application uploading to Google Market I've observe, that it can't be found from tablets.
I've googled about minsdk and xlarge screens, but app still not visible. What else can be done? Application was made on Qt 5.1 for Android - may be this affects me somehow?

Here is my updated manifest:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest package="qqq.qqq" android:versionName="1.11" android:versionCode="11" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.qt_sources_resource_id" android:resource="@array/qt_sources"/>
            <meta-data android:value="@string/repository" android:name="android.app.repository"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.qt_libs_resource_id" android:resource="@array/qt_libs"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundled_libs_resource_id" android:resource="@array/bundled_libs"/>
            <meta-data android:value="lasercad" android:name="android.app.lib_name"/>
            <!-- Deploy Qt libs as part of package -->
            <meta-data android:value="1" android:name="android.app.bundle_local_qt_libs"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundled_in_lib_resource_id" android:resource="@array/bundled_in_lib"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundled_in_assets_resource_id" android:resource="@array/bundled_in_assets"/>
            <!-- Run with local libs -->
            <meta-data android:value="1" android:name="android.app.use_local_qt_libs"/>
            <meta-data android:value="/data/local/tmp/qt/" android:name="android.app.libs_prefix"/>
            <meta-data android:value="plugins/platforms/android/libqtforandroid.so:libs/libgnustl_shared.so:" android:name="android.app.load_local_libs"/>
            <meta-data android:value="jar/QtAndroid-bundled.jar:" android:name="android.app.load_local_jars"/>
            <meta-data android:value=":" android:name="android.app.static_init_classes"/>
            <!--  Messages maps -->
            <meta-data android:value="@string/ministro_not_found_msg" android:name="android.app.ministro_not_found_msg"/>
            <meta-data android:value="@string/ministro_needed_msg" android:name="android.app.ministro_needed_msg"/>
            <meta-data android:value="@string/fatal_error_msg" android:name="android.app.fatal_error_msg"/>
            <!--  Messages maps -->
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="org.j2cpp.CameraTest" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
        <activity android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.StartJavaActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.PhotoIntentActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
        <activity android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.SettingsActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.PREFERENCE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
    <supports-screens android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

update:
here is result of aapt for my apk file:

```
C:\src\Android\sdk\build-tools\17.0.0>aapt.exe dump badging C:\p4\views\AndroidLaser\Src\android\bin\Lasercad-debug.apk
package: name='lasercad.mobile' versionCode='11' versionName='1.11'
application-label:'Lasercad'
application-label-fa:'Lasercad'
application-label-ja:'Lasercad'
application-label-nb:'Lasercad'
application-label-id:'Lasercad'
application-label-de:'Lasercad'
application-label-el:'Lasercad'
application-label-nl:'Lasercad'
application-label-pl:'Lasercad'
application-label-ro:'Lasercad'
application-label-fr:'Lasercad'
application-label-es:'Lasercad'
application-label-ms:'Lasercad'
application-label-rs:'Lasercad'
application-label-et:'Lasercad'
application-label-it:'Lasercad'
application-label-ru:'Lasercad'
application-label-zh_CN:'Lasercad'
application-label-pt_BR:'Lasercad'
application-label-zh_TW:'Lasercad'
application-icon-120:'res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png'
application-icon-160:'res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png'
application-icon-240:'res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png'
application: label='Lasercad' icon='res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png'
application-debuggable
launchable-activity: name='org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity'  label='Lasercad' icon=''
sdkVersion:'10'
targetSdkVersion:'15'
uses-permission:'android.permission.BLUETOOTH'
uses-permission:'android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN'
uses-permission:'android.permission.CAMERA'
uses-permission:'android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission:'android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO'
uses-permission:'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-implied-permission:'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE','requested WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.camera'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.camera.autofocus'
uses-implied-feature:'android.hardware.camera.autofocus','requested android.permission.CAMERA permission'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.bluetooth'
uses-implied-feature:'android.hardware.bluetooth','requested android.permission.BLUETOOTH or android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permission and targetSdkVersion> 4'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.microphone'
uses-implied-feature:'android.hardware.microphone','requested android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO permission'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen'
uses-implied-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen','assumed you require a touch screen unless explicitly made optional'
main
other-activities
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large' 'xlarge'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales: '--_--' 'fa' 'ja' 'nb' 'id' 'de' 'el' 'nl' 'pl' 'ro' 'fr' 'es' 'ms' 'rs' 'et' 'it' 'ru' 'zh_CN' 'pt_BR' 'zh_TW'
densities: '120' '160' '240'
native-code: 'armeabi' 'armeabi-v7a'
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have added the Activity into your Manifest.xml with package name at manifest mode and activity node correctly

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are doing the correct things of

[**uses-feature**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html)

and

**[uses-permission](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html)**

Sometimes you might request feature (or implicitly required some feature via permissions) like phone/gps etc. which are not normally armed on a tablet.

A best practice should be

```
<uses-feature
  android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
  android:required="false" />
```

Comment: In this case - how can it normally work on tablet with such armed features? Also - in user-feature and user-permission I'm doing correct things, because app normally can be download and installed from Marked via phones. Problem is somewhere with Tablet optimization, probably

Comment: I am not quite understand your comment. You can request a feature like GPS, and some 3G tablet does have GPS installed. It is a common problem and I used to be not able to find facebook and twitter on my tablet without GPS, and they have fixed this problem by change the manifest to "use the feature but not 'request the feature to be mandatory'".

Comment: Oh, I understood your point now. How can this "use the feature but not 'request the feature to be mandatory'" can be implemented?

Comment: Sadly, but even removing of this uses-feature not helps. May be there is something else wrong in Manifest?

Comment: Is the full content of your manifest xml file already posted in your question? And have you tried to check all the used features and the ones that might be implicitly requested by the permission declarations?

Comment: Yea, this is full manifest. And putting android:require false also doesn't helps

Comment: You have required bluetooth and camera permission, have you set require=false for both of them? And did you find anything useful from the document section "Special handling for Bluetooth feature"

Comment: Please find updated manifest files in question body. I've added android:required = false, but it seems it still don't want to work for me.

Comment: Also I've attached result of aapt tool for my app - may be it will be useful?